# Crack Me Material

Tags: crackme

I'd like to get started with reverse engineering.

Several years ago I saw many programs called [crackmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crackme), to crack.

When I searched for some this week, I found none.

My question is, can somebody recommend some websites (like crackme walkthroughs) or learning resources to get started with reverse engineering?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here are a bunch:

- https://www.wechall.net/active_sites
- http://www.wechall.net/challs/
- https://crackmes.one
- https://pwnable.xyz/
- https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17
- https://github.com/fdivrp/awesome-reversing/
- https://github.com/michalmalik/linux-re-101
- https://tuts4you.com/download.php
- https://github.com/RPISEC/MBE
- https://github.com/Maijin/Workshop2015/tree/master/IOLI-crackme
- https://github.com/BinaryResearch/IOLI64
- https://hackcenter.com/sign-in
- https://www.root-me.org/en/Challenges/Cracking/
- https://challenges.re/
- https://github.com/s7ephen/CSAW_2009
- https://github.com/isislab/Hack-Night/
- http://pwnable.kr/
- https://w3challs.com/
- http://io.netgarage.org/
- http://rogerfm.net/challenge/crackme/index.htm
- https://gironsec.com/cactuscon_re_challenges/index.php
- https://cryptocult.wordpress.com/cyber-challenges/
- http://www.reteam.org/challenges.html
- https://github.com/rshipp/awesome-malware-analysis
- http://crackmes.cf
- https://0x00sec.org/t/challenge-collection-reverse-engineering-and-crackme/3027
- http://reversing.kr/

Answer (score 12):

- https://dilsec.wordpress.com/2017/07/06/google-ctf-2017-pwnables-inst_prof-writeup/ (Google CTF Writeup)

  - https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~chris/teaching/cs290/projects/proj4.html
    (see Challenge 4 )
  - https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2015/07/announcing_the_secon.html (FLARE)
  - https://cedricvb.be/post/reverse-engineering-the-hitb-binary-100-ctf-challenge/
    (HITB)

**Update:**

- https://github.com/Eun/ctf.tf
- https://0x00sec.org/c/reverse-engineering/challenges
- <strike>http://crackmes.de/</strike> (sadly currently offline - see
  message)

  - you can download a archived version of the website here (Crackmes.de (2011 - 2015)): https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3152

**Update 2:**

- https://challenges.re/

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old posting, I would like to add a long-standing still active site with great challenges (sometimes pretty pretty hard, in the higher levels):
https://overthewire.org/wargames/