# Looking for crackme with full solutions

Tags: crackme

There are lot of crack me site.

I looking for site that have lot of hard crack me/ malware to research anti debug/anti vm... but with full solution

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15774/crack-me-material

Comment: there is no shortage of crackmes with write-ups available; many even have multiple write ups. At [crackmes.one](https://crackmes.one) there are more solutions than actual crackmes.