# What do I need to know in order to reverse-engineer software on Windows?

Tags: windows, x86

My question is: What do I need to know in order to reverse-engineer software on Windows? I have knowledge of Assembly already and now what else I need to learn? Also, can you recommend any book/resource to learn from? 
(I have found some resources about reversing from The Legend of R4ndom. What do you think about these?)

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13829/good-foundation-for-reverse-engineering-malware and https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15774/crack-me-material/15775

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge on assembly is all you really need to get started. To reverse executables on Window learn the Disassembler ([IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)) and Debuggers ([WinDbg](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg), [OllyDbg](http://ollydbg.de/)) as well as the Windows API , if you plan to reverse Windows specific software. Crackmes and keygens are great resource for learning and I would recommend [crackme.de](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.3152), as it contains lots of windows executables.

Comment: Do you know where I can learn more about the Windows PE format the headers and everything else about it? Because this is something that I don't know how it works.

Comment: @BoSsYyY https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/master/binary/pe101/pe101.pdf https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/master/binary/pe102/pe102.pdf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3duSgr5b1yc https://www.nostarch.com/malware